# Padding on button in iOS

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

Having problem with extra padding on a `<button>` element in iOS safari browser.

The markup is like this, using font-awesome icons:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-class">
   <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

This is the CSS for the class in the button element:

```
background: #000;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 100%;
border: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
```

On a computer with Chrome as the browser I get this output.

[image]

But when using iPhone iOS 8.1.2 and Safari there is a strange padding to the left of the plus sign:

[image]

Any ideas on what the problem is?

**EDIT**

here is a fiddle on the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/qpvat7xv/

Comment: Please post the full CSS for `btn-class` and `fa fa-plus`.

Comment: do you use css reset on your page?

Comment: Could you share the page(or on jsfiddle)?

Comment: @Nima fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/qpvat7xv/

Comment: @grahlie Thanks. Just found the problem, please check the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add `padding: 0` to your `<button>` style:

```
button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
    text-transform: none;
    padding:0;
}
```

This will solve the bug with `Button` tag which creates the padding in iOS.